# Is it possible to create a new .po file from a translation?

Tags: translation, gettext, language-translation, po, poedit

I have a .po file in which the source text is in Spanish and the translation is in English.

I've tried checking around to get this English translation and create a new .po file from it to be translated into Brazilian Portuguese, but I couldn't find anything in POEdit to do so.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit: Just to be more precise, I have the source language as Spanish and the translation as English. I want to use this English translation as the source language in a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less possible to achieve by using the `msghack` tool on command line.

Like this:

```
msghack --invert en.po > inv.po
msghack --empty inv.po > yourapp.pot
```

Duplicate translations are apparently silently ignored when inverting; this may not be a problem, but better be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

See the *File → New from PO/POT file…* menu.

Comment: Doing this just creates a new file with the Spanish source text, not the English one

Comment: @LucasFarinazzoMarques You do realize you failed to mention that you want to change the *source* language, right? Even if you did this, such file would be of no use to you because the code you're translating wouldn't be able to find the translations...

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I have the source language as Spanish and the translation as English, now, I want to use this English translation as the source language in a new file